# How does tmux spawn multiple sessions?

Tags: environment-variables, tmux

I noticed something peculiar while working with multiple tmux sessions. I'm not certain on all the terminology so please correct me if I get something wrong.

Creating tmux sessions beyond the first does not inherit the environment it was created from, they inherit the environment that spawned the first session.

```
export a=false; export b=false

bash
export a=true
tmux new-session -d -s first

bash
export b=true
tmux new-session -d -s second
```

then executing `echo $a $b` from either session gives the output `true false`. I was expecting `true true` for the second session.

I don't know how tmux "remembers" the environment of the first session. I can perform another experiment:

If I update the environment in the first session, detach, and spawn a second session, the second session does not inherit the update.

And another experiment:

If I exit the subshell after creating the first session (thus "forgetting" the environment variable `a`), and spawn a second session, the second session still remembers the environment.

I'd like to better know why this is happening and some of what tmux is doing under-the-hood, so any advice in that direction is appreciated.

Comment: Can you spawn Bash as `bash -l`? I don’t believe environment variables are passed unless the `-l` parameter is there.

Comment: This had no impact for me. On my system bash starts an interactive session by default and will source .profile if passed with -l

Comment: I just faced the same problem and it's a complete non-sense... I moved to tmux from screen thinking it'd be better, but it's worse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a section named `ENVIRONMENT` in `man 1 tmux`:

> When the server is started, `tmux` copies the environment into the global environment; in addition, each session has a session environment.  When a window is created, the session and global environments are merged. If a variable exists in both, the value from the session environment is used. The result is the initial environment passed to the new process.
>
> The `update-environment` session option may be used to update the session environment from the client when a new session is created or an old reattached. […]
>
> Commands to alter and view the environment are:
>
> `set-environment` […]
>
> `show-environment` […]

And where the manual explains `set-option`, it reads:

> `update-environment variables`
>
> Set a space-separated string containing a list of environment variables to be copied into the session environment when a new session is created or an existing session is attached.
>
> […] The default is `"DISPLAY SSH_ASKPASS SSH_AUTH_SOCK SSH_AGENT_PID SSH_CONNECTION WINDOWID XAUTHORITY"`.

So your `a` and `b` are copied to `tmux` only when the server starts. In your case it's when you create the `first` session. These variables are not on the list stored by `update-environment` option, so later they are not updated.

If you did

```
tmux set-option -t second update-environment "a b"
```

and then attached to this session, your current variables would be absorbed by `tmux`. This doesn't mean `echo $a $b` would show them in the shell that had already been started (by `tmux new-session -d -s first`). But a new shell (or any other process) in a new pane would inherit them from `tmux`.

It's possible to set the option globally. See the `OPTIONS` section. But keep these things in mind:

- the option is designed to work when a new session is created or *an old reattached* (although you can change the behavior with `-E` option of `attach-session`; few other commands also support `-E`);
- the updated value won't affect existing processes (panes).

To summarize: in general `tmux` sessions and processes within don't simply inherit the environment from the client like a simple child process would do.

Comment: what a BS behavior and design decision... I expected it to take all my env vars so that I don't need to list them all...