# Systemd Service Restart When Program in Tmux Window Fails

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, tmux, systemd

I have a dotnet program running inside of bash in tmux which occasionally fails with a non-zero error code. I am attempting to use a systemd service file to programmatically start my dotnet program inside of tmux.

Here is the service file:

```
[Unit] 
Description=dotnet application

[Service] 
Type=forking 
ExecStart=/home/alpine_sour/scripts/rofdl
Restart=always 
User=root

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Here is the rofdl shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash 
/usr/bin/tmux kill-session -t "rof" 2> /dev/null || true 
/usr/bin/tmux new -s "rof" -d "cd /home/alpine_sour/rofdl && dotnet run"
```

Now, when I start the service, systemd chooses the main PID as the tmux server, which I assume is because it was the first executed command. Therefore, when my program in the tmux window exits with ANY error code AND there are no more windows, the tmux server exits with a success error code, causing the systemd not to restart. Even if I were to Restart=always, the tmux server would only restart if my program fails AND there are no other windows.

```
  Process: 24980 ExecStart=/home/alpine_sour/scripts/rofdl (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 24984 (tmux: server)
           ├─24984 /usr/bin/tmux new -s rofdl -d cd /home/alpine_sour/rofdl && dotnet run -- start
           ├─24985 sh -c cd /home/alpine_sour/rofdl && dotnet run -- start
           ├─24987 dotnet run -- start
           └─25026 dotnet exec /home/alpine_sour/rofdl/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/rofdl.dll start
```

So I'm wondering how I would get systemd to track the lowest level of the process fork rather than the higher level tmux server. I need a way to tell systemd to track the child process of the tmux server rather than the server itself and restart accordingly.

Comment: If you can put the pid of the interesting process in a file, you might have some luck using `PIDFile=...`

Comment: Good idea. I'll check that out, and maybe have my inner command inside tmux spit out a PIDFile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Preliminary notes

- This answer is based on experiments in Debian 9.
- I assume your service is a system service (in `/etc/systemd/system`).
- What you posted near the end of the question body looks like an *excerpt* from `systemctl status …`. It says nothing about cgroups. This answer assumes [Control Groups](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroup-v1/cgroups.txt) are involved. I think `systemd` requires them, so they must be.
- The command itself may run in a loop, until it succeeds:

  ```
  cd /home/alpine_sour/rofdl && while ! dotnet run; do :; done
  ```

  but I understand you want a `systemd` solution.

---

## Problems

First please read [how `tmux` works](https://superuser.com/a/1472783/432690). Understanding which process is whose child will be very helpful.

#### Which processes belong to the service

In your original case the service will be considered inactive (and ready to restart, if applicable) after all processes from its cgroup exit.

Your script tries to kill the old `tmux` session, not the old `tmux` server. Then `tmux new` (equivalent to `tmux new-session`) either starts a server or uses the old one.

- If it uses the old one then neither the server nor your command (`dotnet …`) will be a descendant of the script. These processes will not belong to the cgroup associated with the service. After the script exits, `systemd` will consider the service inactive.
- If it starts a new `tmux` server then the server and the command will be assigned to the cgroup associated with the service. Then our command may terminate but if there are other sessions/windows (created later) within the server, the server may remain and `systemd` will consider the service active.

If there is one main process, the whole cgroup gets killed after the main process exits. With `Type=simple` the main process is the one specified by `ExecStart=`. With `Type=forking` you need to use `PIDFile=` and pass a PID this way to specify the main process. And when you stop a service, `systemd` kills all processes that belong to the service. Therefore it's important to include only processes specific to the service in the cgroup. In your case you may want to exclude `tmux` server, even if it's started from within the service.

There are tools/ways to move processes between cgroups. Or you can run a separate `tmux` server specific to the service.

#### How `systemd` knows which exit status to use

`Restart=on-failure` sets dependency on the exit status of the main process. With `Type=forking` it's advised to use `PIDFile=` so `systemd` knows what exit status to use.

`systemd` may or may not be able to retrieve the exit status though.

#### Who retrieves exit status

After a child exits, its parent can retrieve the exit status (compare [*zombie process*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process)).

Regardless whether the `tmux` server is old or new, your command won't be a child of `systemd` unless it gets orphaned, the kernel sets its parent to PID 1 ([or some other](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/177361/108618)) and the new parent is the right `systemd`.

The command you provide to `tmux new` makes the `tmux` server run a shell, then the shell either runs `dotnet` and waits for it to exit, or `exec`s to `dotnet` while keeping the `tmux` server as a parent. In any case `dotnet` has a parent which is not `systemd`.

You could orphan `dotnet` like this: `nohup dotnet … &`, then let the said shell exit. You would also need to store the PID, use `PIDFile=` in the unit configuration file, so the service knows which process to monitor. Then it might kinda work.

To be clear: in my tests `nohup sleep 300 &` was successfully adopted by `systemd` who could then retrieve its exit status (after I took care of cgroups).

But since you want to use `tmux` in the first place, I guess your command interacts with the terminal. So [`nohup`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/3886/108618) is not the right tool here. Orphaning a process while keeping it connected to the terminal may be tricky. You want to orphan it but you cannot let the shell within `tmux` simply exit, because this will kill its pane (or leave it in a dead state).

Note `Type=forking` relies on adoption by `systemd`. The main service process is supposed to fork and exit. Then `systemd` adopts its child. Such daemon should not interact with any terminal though.

Another approach is to let the shell within the `tmux` server `exec` to `dotnet`. After it exits, the `tmux` server (as a parent) knows its exit status. In some circumstances we can query the server from another script and retrieve the exit status.

Or the shell triggered by `tmux new` may store the status in a file, so it can be retrieved by another script.

Because what you run with `ExecStart=` is a child of `systemd` for sure, this is the best candidate for "another script". It should wait until it can retrieve the exit status, then use it as its own exit status, so `systemd` gets it. Note the service should be `Type=simple` in this case.

Alternatively you can start `dotnet …` outside of `tmux`, then [`reptyr`](https://superuser.com/a/1293299/432690) from the inside of the `tmux` server. This way `dotnet` can be a child of `systemd` from the very beginning, problems may appear when you try to steal its tty.

---

## Solutions and examples

#### `reptyr` to `tmux`

This example runs the script in `tty2`. The script prepares `tmux` and `exec`s to `dotnet`. Finally a shell within `tmux` tries to steal tty of what is now `dotnet`.

The service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=dotnet application
After=getty@tty2.service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/home/alpine_sour/scripts/rofdl
Restart=on-failure
User=root
StandardInput=tty
TTYPath=/dev/tty2
TTYReset=yes
TTYVHangup=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

`/home/alpine_sour/scripts/rofdl`:

```
#!/bin/sh
tmux="/usr/bin/tmux"

"$tmux" kill-session -t "rof" 2> /dev/null
"$tmux" new-session -s "rof" -d "sleep 5; exec /usr/bin/reptyr $$" || exit 1

cd /home/alpine_sour/rofdl && exec dotnet run
```

Notes:

- My tests with `htop` instead of `dotnet run` revealed a race condition (`htop` changes settings of its terminal, `reptyr` can interfere; hence `sleep 5` as a poor workaround) and problems with mouse support.
- It's possible to remove the `tmux` server from the cgroup associated with the service. You probably want to do this. See way below, where there is `/sys/fs/cgroup/systemd/` in the code.

#### Without `tmux`?

The above solution uses `/dev/tty2` anyway. If you need `tmux` only to provide a controlling terminal, consider `cd /home/alpine_sour/rofdl && exec dotnet run` without `reptyr`, without `tmux`. Even without the script:

```
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c 'cd /home/alpine_sour/rofdl && exec dotnet run' rofdl
```

This is the simplest.

#### Separate `tmux` server

`tmux` allows you to run more than one server per user. You need `-L` or `-S` (see `man 1 tmux`) to specify a socket, then stick to it. This way your service can run an exclusive `tmux` server. Advantages:

- The server and everything you run within this `tmux` belongs to the cgroup of the service by default.
- The service can destroy the `tmux` server without a risk that anyone (or anything) else loses their sessions. Nobody else should use this server, unless they want to monitor/interact with the service. If anyone uses it for anything else, it's their problem.

The ability to kill the `tmux` server freely allows you to orphan processes that run in `tmux`. Consider the following example.

The service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=dotnet application

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/home/alpine_sour/scripts/rofdl
Restart=on-failure
User=root
PIDFile=/var/run/rofdl.service.pid

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

`/home/alpine_sour/scripts/rofdl`:

```
#!/bin/sh
tmux="/usr/bin/tmux"
service="rofdl.service"

"$tmux" -L "$service" kill-server 2> /dev/null
"$tmux" -L "$service" new-session -s "rof" -d '
      trap "" HUP
      ppid="$PPID"
      echo "$$" > '" '/var/run/$service.pid' "'
      cd /home/alpine_sour/rofdl && dotnet run
      status="$?"
   '" '$tmux' -L '$service' kill-server 2> /dev/null "'
      while [ "$ppid" -eq "$(ps -o ppid= -p "$$")" ]; do sleep 2; done
      exit "$status"
  ' || exit 1
```

Explanation:

1. The main script kills the exclusive `tmux` server (if any) and starts it anew. After the server is started, the script exits. The service remains because there is at least one process left in the cgroup, the said server.
2. The server spawns a shell to process the "inner" script. The script begins at `'` after `-d` and ends at `'` before `||`. It's all quoted, but quoting changes from single- to double-quotes and back few times. It's because `$tmux` and `$service` need to be expanded by the shell processing the main script, other variables (e.g. `$status`) must not be expanded until in the "inner" shell, inside `tmux`. The following resource may be helpful: [*Parameter expansion (variable expansion) and quotes within quotes*](https://superuser.com/q/1404244/432690).
3. The shell inside `tmux` prepares to ignore `HUP` signal.
4. The shell registers its PID in the pidfile the service expects.
5. Then it runs `dotnet` and stores its exit status (strictly, if `cd` fails then it will be the exit status of `cd`).
6. The shell kills the `tmux` server. We could do this with `kill "$PPID"` as well (see [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/509251/108618)), but if somebody had killed the server and another process got its PID, we would kill a wrong process. Addressing `tmux` is safer. Because of the `trap` the shell survives.
7. Then the shell loops until its PPID is different than what it was before. We cannot rely on comparing `$ppid` to `$PPID` because the latter is not dynamic; we retrieve the current PPID from `ps`.
8. Now the shell knows it has a new parent, it should be `systemd`. Only now `systemd` is able to retrieve exit status from the shell. The shell exits with the exact exit status retrieved from `dotnet` earlier. This way `systemd` gets the exit status despite the fact `dotnet` was never its child.

#### Retrieving exit status from common `tmux` server

Your original approach uses a common (default) `tmux` server, it only manipulates a session named `rof`. In general other sessions may exist or arise, so the service should never kill the whole server. There are few aspects. We should:

- prevent `systemd` from killing the `tmux` server, even if the server was started from within the service;
- make `systemd` consider `dotnet` process a part of the service, even if it was started from `tmux` not started from within the service;
- retrieve the exit status from `dotnet` somehow.

The service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=dotnet application

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/home/alpine_sour/scripts/rofdl
Restart=on-failure
User=root

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Note it's `Type=simple` now, because the main script is the only assured child we can retrieve the exit status from. The script needs to find out the exit status of `dotnet …` and report it as its own.

`/home/alpine_sour/scripts/rofdl`:

```
#!/bin/sh
tmux="/usr/bin/tmux"
service="rofdl.service"
slice="/sys/fs/cgroup/systemd/system.slice"

"$tmux" kill-session -t "rof" 2> /dev/null
( sh -c 'echo "$PPID"' > "$slice/tasks"
  exec "$tmux" new-session -s "rof" -d "
      '$tmux' set-option -t 'rof' remain-on-exit on "'
      echo "$$" > '" '$slice/$service/tasks' "'
      cd /home/alpine_sour/rofdl && dotnet run
      exit "$?"
    ' || exit 1
)

pane="$("$tmux" display-message -p -t "rof" "#{pane_id}")"

while sleep 2; do
  [ "$("$tmux" display-message -p -t "$pane" "#{pane_dead}")" -eq 0 ] || {
    status="$("$tmux" display-message -p -t "$pane" "#{pane_dead_status}")"
    status="${status:-255}"
    exit "$status"
  }
done
```

Explanation:

1. If `tmux new-session` creates a server (because there was none), we want it in another cgroup from the very beginning to prevent race condition when something else starts using the server and we haven't change its cgroup yet and `systemd` decides to kill the service for whatever reason. I tried to run `tmux new-session` with `cgexec` and failed; therefore another approach: a subshell which changes its own cgroup (by writing to `/sys/fs/cgroup/systemd/system.slice/tasks`) and then `exec`s to `tmux new-session`.
2. The shell inside `tmux` starts by enabling `remain-on-exit` option for the session. After it exits, the pane remains and another process (the main script in our case) can retrieve its exit status from the `tmux` server.
3. In the meantime the main script retrieves the unique ID of the pane the other shell runs in. If someone attaches to the session or creates new panes and plays with them, the main script will still be able to find the right pane.
4. The shell inside `tmux` registers its PID in the cgroup associated with the service by writing it to `/sys/fs/cgroup/systemd/system.slice/rofdl.service/tasks`.
5. The shell inside `tmux` runs `dotnet …`. After `dotnet` terminates, the shell exits. Exit status retrieved from `dotnet` is reported by the shell to the `tmux` server.
6. Because of `remain-on-exit on`, the pane remains in a dead state after the "inner" shell exits.
7. In the meantime the main shell loops until the pane is dead. Then it queries the `tmux` server for the relevant exit status and reports it as its own. This way `systemd` gets the exit status from `dotnet`.

Notes:

- Again there are [quotes within quotes](https://superuser.com/q/1404244/432690).
- Instead of `dotnet run` it could be `exec dotnet run`. The last form is nice: `dotnet` replaces the inner shell, so there is one process instead of two. The problem is when `dotnet` is killed by a signal it cannot handle. It turns out `#{pane_dead_status}` will report an empty string if the process in the pane is forcefully killed by a signal. Maintaining a shell between `dotnet` and `tmux` prevents this: the shell transforms information (see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/99112/108618)) and returns a number.

  Some shells (implementations?) run the very last command with implicit `exec`, something we don't want. That's why I used `exit "$?"` after `dotnet …`.

  But if the shell itself is forcefully killed, the problem with empty `#{pane_dead_status}` reappears. As the last resort `status="${status:-255}"` converts empty status to `255` (although I'm not sure `255` is the best value in such case).
- There's a race condition: when the main script queries `tmux` for `#{pane_id}`, it may not be the right pane. If somebody attached and played inside the session after `tmux new-session` and before `tmux display-message`, we might get a wrong pane. The time window is small, still this is not as elegant as I wanted.

  If `tmux new-session` could print `#{pane_id}` to the console like `tmux display-message -p` can, there should be no problem. With `-PF` it can show it within the session. There is no support for `-p`.
- You may want some logic in case the `tmux` server gets killed.

#### Retrieving exit status via file

The above example can be modified, so `remain-on-exit on` is not needed, `#{pane_id}` is not needed (race condition avoided, at least the described one).

The service file from the previous example remains.

`/home/alpine_sour/scripts/rofdl`:

```
#!/bin/sh
tmux="/usr/bin/tmux"
service="rofdl.service"
slice="/sys/fs/cgroup/systemd/system.slice"
statf="/var/run/$service.status"

rm "$statf" 2>/dev/null

"$tmux" kill-session -t "rof" 2> /dev/null
( sh -c 'echo "$PPID"' > "$slice/tasks"
  exec "$tmux" new-session -s "rof" -d '
      echo "$$" > '" '$slice/$service/tasks' "'
      cd /home/alpine_sour/rofdl && dotnet run
      echo "$?" > '" '$statf.tmp'
      mv '$statf.tmp' '$statf'
    " || exit 1
)

while sleep 2; do
  status="$(cat "$statf" 2>/dev/null)" && exit "$status"
done
```

The mechanism is pretty straightforward: the main shell removes the old status file (if any), triggers `tmux` and loops until the file reappears. The "inner" shell writes the exit status of `dotnet` to the file, when ready.

Notes:

- What if the inner shell is killed? What if the file cannot be created? It's relatively easy to get to a situation where the main script cannot exit the loop.
- Writing to a temporary file and then renaming is a good practice. If we did `echo "$?" > "$statf"`, the file would be created empty, then written to. This might lead to a situation when the main script reads an empty string as status. In general the receiver might get incomplete data: reading until EOF while the sender is mid-write and the file is yet about to grow. Renaming makes the right file with the right content appear instantly.

---

## Final notes

- If you cannot go without `tmux`, the solution with a separate `tmux` server seems most robust.
- This is what the [documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html) says about `Restart=`:

  > In this context, a clean exit means an exit code of `0`, or one of the signals `SIGHUP`, `SIGINT`, `SIGTERM` or `SIGPIPE`, and […]

  Note `$?` in a shell is just a number. Again: [this link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/99112/108618). If your `dotnet` exits because of a signal and restarting depends on (un-)clean exit, the solutions where `systemd` retrieves exit code directly from `dotnet` may behave differently than solutions where `systemd` retrieves exit status from an intermediary shell. Research `SuccessExitStatus=`, it may be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `RestartForceExitStatus=` in service file

> Takes a list of exit status definitions that, when returned by the main service process, will force automatic service restarts, regardless of the restart setting configured with Restart=. The argument format is similar to RestartPreventExitStatus=.

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html

Comment: Thanks. However, I don't want to restart on the server process. I want to restart based on one of its children